# How to use conditional statements or loops to achieve my requirement?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to python coding. Kindly, help me to achieve my requirement.

Suppose there are two arrays 'a' and 'b' of size 3*4

```
a = [[1,0,0,1],
     [0,0,1,1],
     [1,0,0,1]]

b = [[12,-34,-10,4],
     [2,11,-12,20],
     [-12,16,19,-9]]
```

Here, if `b[i,j]<10` than I want the corresponding `a[i,j]` to be same(i.e it can be either 0 or 1) else change `a[i,j]` element to 1.

Expected outcome for the above example :

```
c = [[1,0,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the or `|` operator:

```
In [11]: b >= 10
Out[11]:
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False]])

In [12]: a | (b >= 10)
Out[12]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

The `|` is a bitwise or and is equivalent to [np.bitwise_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html):

```
In [13]: np.bitwise_or(a, b >= 10)
Out[13]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

---

This assumes both a and b are numpy arrays, you can make this so with the array constructor:

```
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)
```

Comment: could you direct us to a `doc` link for an extra explanation?

Comment: @umn hmm! I will add something, so far I've found this helpful link.. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__or__.html. Ah, I found [bitwise_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html)

Comment: It will only work with `numpy` array, not with the python default list data type. If you are using list then you should try loops to achieve this.

Comment: List initialization doesn't have the `numpy array` data type. It's somewhat confusing.

Comment: by application of a | (b >= 10) . where did the new array(output) got stored ? I mean in a new variable or replace the existing values in a ?

Comment: @SaiKiran you can do `a =| (b >= 10)` to replace the existing values in a, otherwise it's a new variable (i.e. you need to do `c = ` before it to use)

Comment: @AndyHayden in practical situation my `a` data type is boolean and `b` dtype is 'float32'

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use numpy you could do this nested list-comprehension:

```
c = [[el_a | (el_b >= 10) for el_a, el_b in zip(row_a, row_b)] 
      for row_a, row_b in zip(a, b)]
```

but i prefer [Andy Hayden's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231436/4954037). numpy really shines for that kind of operations.